# How to select into varray in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to save a set of ids in array:

```
create or replace type vrray_4 as varray(4) of varchar2(10);

create or replace procedure get_acl_owner_exchange (id in varchar2 ) is 
   path_count int;
   acl_type out vrray_4;
begin
   select owner_id into acl_type from kmc_acl_perm
   where  permission_name = 'read.'
   or     permission_name = 'write.'
   or     permission_name = 'delete.';
end get_acl_owner_exchange;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3/17     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VRRAY_4" when expecting one of the following:
         := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "VRRAY_4" to continue.
```

Comment: Please show us the error message and the structure of the table, ideally with some example data.

Comment: Hthis is my error : pls 00103 encountered the symbol create procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `OUT` parameter in the wrong place and you need to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` rather than just `INTO`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5dc9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE KMC_ACL_PERM(
  owner_id        VARCHAR2(10),
  permission_name VARCHAR2(10)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vrray_4 AS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(10)
/

create or replace PROCEDURE GET_ACL_OWNER_EXCHANGE (
  id       IN  VARCHAR2,
  acl_type OUT VRRAY_4
) IS 
BEGIN
  SELECT owner_id
  bulk collect into   acl_type 
  from   KMC_ACL_PERM
  where  permission_name IN ( 'read.', 'write.', 'delete.' );
END GET_ACL_OWNER_EXCHANGE;
/
```

Comment: You committed while I was still writing :-). What to do now?

Comment: @wolφi Nothing needs doing now, it happens that people post similar answers at similar times - although, in this case, our answers are different as you have a local variable for the `VARRAY` whereas I have it as an `OUT` parameter. Both are equally valid different answers depending on how the syntax errors in the OP's question are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vrray_4 AS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(10);
/

CREATE TABLE kmc_acl_perm (
  owner_id VARCHAR2(10),
  permission_name VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_acl_owner_exchange (id IN VARCHAR2) IS 
  path_count NUMBER;
  acl_type vrray_4;
BEGIN
  SELECT owner_id BULK COLLECT INTO acl_type
    FROM kmc_acl_perm
   WHERE permission_name IN ('read.', 'write.', 'delete.');
END get_acl_owner_exchange;
/
```